# Not getting json response from online server

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, background-task

So I came over this tutorial right here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdAXqQoADt8 (last part of it) everything is working absolutly fine when I'm refering to my local server.

Now I switched it up to an online server/database to test if it works the same way. Also here everything is working fine except of the json response in the **onPostExecute** **Method**. I'm getting no messages from registration or login anymore. I really can't figure out how to solve this problem and I don't understand why it doesn't work the same way when I switch it up to an online server/database.

Hope anyone here can help me with that. I'll post some code below, maybe somebody can figure it out without doing the whole tutorial.

Thankful for any help!

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

        try {
            Log.d("JSON-String",json+"");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String code = JO.getString("code");
            String message = JO.getString("message");
            if (code.equals("reg_true"))
            {
                showDialog("Registrierung erfolgt.", message, code);
            }
            else if (code.equals("reg_false"))
            {
                showDialog("Registrierung fehlgeschlagen", message, code);
            }

            else if(code.equals("login_true"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Talkscreen.class);                                        //SPÄTER WIEDER RAUSNEHMEN
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();
            }
            else if (code.equals("login_false"))
            {
                showDialog("Login fehlgeschlagen", message,code);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` Is it going in exception ? Or what you're getting in output ? Did you try to log the json string in above function ?

Comment: @Alok so I'm relativly new to android programming. I can only tell you that it is not going into exception and I'm not getting anything in output. I updated my code so you can take a look at it by yourself because I cannot surely awnser your question If I've logged the json string in above function.

Comment: Are you able to see Debug logs in which every IDE you're using ? If you're not sure how to see the logs ? Refer: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#systemLogView

Comment: I'm unable to see any exceptions in log. Is it full log ? Try to login or register and provide the entire log please.

Comment: @Alok sorry my mistake. Of cause you're not able to see anything if I don't do anything. Updated my code, this is after I've tried to login.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110002/discussion-between-alok-and-ron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're getting wrong JSON string from the server.

```
2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <h3>DB< of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at com.appmac.ron.testapp.ServerKlassen.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:172)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at com.appmac.ron.testapp.ServerKlassen.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:39)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-23 12:35:53.172 2905-2905/com.appmac.ron.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

> Above error shows that String could not be converted to JSON object.

Check the server code for any bug.

Comment: As you said, adding 'Log.d("JSON-String",json+"");' to my code solved the problem! Thanks alot!